# Does anyone know how to pull averages from a text file for several different people?

Tags: python-3.x, list, average

I have a text file (Player_hits.text) that I am trying to pull player batting averages from. Similar to lines 179-189 I want to find an average. However, I do not want to find the average for the entire team. Instead, I want to find the average of every individual player on the team.

For instance, the text file is set up as such:
[Player_hits.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8SGH.png)

In this file a 1 defines a hit and a 0 means the player did not get a hit. I am trying to pull an individual average for both players. (Alex = 0.500, Riley = 0.666)
If someone could help, that would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Link to original code on repl.it: [Baseball Stat-Tracking](https://replit.com/@RILEYSENFTEN/Baseball-Stat-tracking#main.py)

[JSONDecodeError Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMdwy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:` is coming because the `json.loads()` doesn't interpret that (each line, `'[[1, 'Riley']\n'`as valid json format. You can use `ast` to read in that list as a literal evaluation, thus storing that as a list element `[', 'Riley']` in your list of `p_hits`.

Then the second part is you can convert to the dataframe and groupby the `'name'` column. So jim has the right idea, but there's errors in that too (Ie. `colmuns` should be `columns`, and the items in the list need to be strings `['hit','name']`, not undeclared variables.

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

p_hits = []

with open('Player_hits.txt') as hits:
    for line in hits:
        l = ast.literal_eval(line)
        p_hits.append(l)

df = pd.DataFrame(p_hits, columns=['hit', 'name'])
```

**Output:** with an example dataset I made

```
print(df.groupby(['name']).mean())
            hit
name           
Matt   0.714286
Riley  0.285714
Todd   0.500000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import json

p_hits = []

with open('Player_hits.txt') as hits:
    for line in hits:
        l = json.loads(line)
        p_hits.append(l)


df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(p_hits, colmuns=[hit, name])

df.groupby(['name']).mean()
```

Comment: That fixed the problem of undefined 'data'. Now I am getting an error 'json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting Value: line 1 column 5 (char 4). I attached an image above on the original post.

Comment: Also, there should be no apostrophe in "player's" in your first line of text - poor grammar.